# Use iis7 rewrite/redirect to strip leading zeroes of numbers and forward on

Tags: iis-7

I need to be able to take an incoming url, remove some leading zeroes, and forward/redirect it on somewhere else. This is on a Server 2008 64 bit box with IIS7 and Rewrite manager installed.

Incoming link:

```
http://myserver/?PatientID=000123456
```

And flip it to

```
http://myserver2/?PatientID=123456
```

Comment: Something to drink, sir? http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Install URL Rewrite and then learn how to configure it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#functionality-overview

Answer (score 0):

A URL Rewrite rule like the following would work.  If you are hoping to "forward" the request instead of "redirect" the request, you'll need ApplicationRequestRouting as well

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="TrimZerosAndRedirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="PatientID=0*(\d+)" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.google.com/?PatientID={C:1}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Temporary" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Also, I must say:  Your OS is out of support and there are major security concerns with running an outdated OS like this.  Please urge the owner to consider upgrading this box.

Comment: Thanks Rich-Lang I will try this Monday!  And yes we are working towards upgrading the Os prior to Jan 2020.